# Button text mid, Icon right: justify-content

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Im using this html code from the template below. The problem is that it uses justify-content for the icon and the text.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-icon-split">
        <span class="icon">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="text">Search</span>
    </a>
</button>
```

I need the icon left and text centered.

```
.btn-icon-split {
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
}

.btn-icon-split .icon {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
}

.btn-icon-split .text {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
}
```

Tried to get it working by using float, bootstrap pull-right stuff, ...

Im using the following bs theme: https://startbootstrap.com/themes/sb-admin-2/

Comment: Do you have a link to the site your actually working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem by taking the icon out of the normal document flow with `absolute` position:

```css
.btn {
  width: 300px;
}

.btn-icon-split {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
}

.btn-icon-split .icon {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.btn-icon-split .text {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-icon-split">
        <span class="icon">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="text">Search</span>
</button>
```

Another option that comes to mind is adding 'helper' span after the text with the same width as icon that's in front of the text, and using `space-between`.